# Where is .gdbinit is located and how can I edit it?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am having a exception crash issue and I am trying to edit this file to get more info about the crash.

Where is `.gdbinit` is located and how can I edit it?

Answer (score 27):

You can also put `.gdbinit` in your debugging folder, this makes more applicable for debugging different apps. GDB will automatically load `./.gdbinit` for current debugging.

Answer (score 25):

You need to create a new file called .gdbinit - put it in your home directory. Now every time gdb starts it will execute the commands in this file. ".gdbinit" is a file you can drop in your home directory that gdb will parse when gdb launches, either from the command line or from within Xcode.

Comment: Thanks now I have the .gdbinit file in my home directory.  Where can I locate the crash result?

Comment: You can add this system default to your .gdbinit to log Xcode's GDB output to a file. So when you execute your program, your logs will be written to the log file:

defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDEGDBLogToFile /tmp/logs.txt

Answer (score 6):

You can do

```
nano ~/.gdbinit
```

modify your file and save it. Verify the changes with `cat ~/.gdbinit`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to add the line `echo "set disassembly intel" > ~/.gdbinit`. For example:

```
gdb@Name:~$ echo "set disassembly intel" > ~/.gdbinit
gdb@Name:~$ cat ~/.gdbinit
set disassembly intel
gdb@Name:
```

Answer (score -1):

go to the root directory using cd ~/ or cd root, then create .gdbinit