# I want to demo my program using gdb and a makefile script, but make won't execute further commands after gdb

Tags: makefile, gdb

Here is my makefile code

```
all: ass3

ass3: ass3.asm
    nasm -f elf ass3.asm
    ld -m elf_i386 -s ass3.o -o demo
    echo Start debugging\n
    gdb demo
    echo Breakpoint after first case has been calculated\n
    b *0x804809e
    echo Printing 1st case answer\n
    i ecx
    echo Breakpoint after second case has been calculated\n
    b *0x80480ba
    i ecx
    echo Breakpoint on third case showing the execution path when the difference of time    is negative\n
    b *0x8048113
    echo Since Initial time is large than final time, it will jump to an error catcher\n
    r
    echo Program caught the error and terminated the program\n

binaries = demo

clean: 
    rm -f $(binaries) *~
```

When I type make, it stops on gdb and when I press "q" (which is quit), It just proceeds executing the echo until it stops on b *0x804809e which is a gdb command

How do I make my makefile code do a demo run on gdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gdb starts its own prompt so you can't interact with it directly.

It reads `.gdbinit` on launch after starting so you can modify that to automate it.

**Edit :**

These questions might help you :

1. [What are the best ways to automate a GDB debugging session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748501/automating-gdb-sessions)
2. [Where is .gdbinit is located and how can I edit it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573683/where-is-gdbinit-is-located-and-how-can-i-edit-itm)

Comment: Looks like I cannot do these I guess. I just tried the gdbinit method and looks like the machine is protected on where I'm working at. It spits error "auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path". Thanks for the help anyways