# gdb error with Sierra OS upgrade

Tags: gdb, macos-sierra

I just upgraded to Sierra OS and after I load a file into gdb, set a breakpoint and attempt to run the program, I get the error "During startup program terminated with signal SIG113, Real-time event 113." Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: does this happen with every program? What happens when you debug "helloWorld" ?

Comment: Yes, all programs. I also get the problem with hello_world.cpp

Comment: Go here to fix the issue easily: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702871/gdb-kind-of-doesnt-work-on-macos-sierra/40437725#40437725

Answer (score 2):

> *1st* Solution: **by disabling SIP**

- Boot to Recovery OS by restarting your machine and holding down the
  `CMD + R` keys at startup.
- Launch Terminal from the Utilities
  menu.
- Enter the following command: `csrutil disable`
- Restart OS
- GDC is now working, happy debugging!

  **What's SIP?** [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016462-CH5-SW1)
  **How to re-enable SIP again?** Repeat previous steps using `csrutil enable`
  **What if I don't want to disable SIP?** Continue reading..

---

> *2nd* Solution: **by leaving GDC**

- **using Native LLDB:**   Just install XCode. It's available for free from the App Store. It will install all the command line tools as well.
- **using Non-Native via Brew, Ports, .. etc :**   It's too easy to install ex. `brew install llvm --with-lldb --with-clang` However you'll have to code-sign it too, so **DON'T** go that way!

Comment: Turning off SIP didn't fix the problem here, and I've tried it on two computers. I still get the same `During startup program terminated with signal SIG113, Real-time event 113.` error. :(

Comment: No luck with this on 10.12.4

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Patched Version
Compiled and tested >> Mac OS "Sierra 10.12.1 (16B2555)"

https://mega.nz/#!VkBWVJ7J!LzA51cXfWPK_o7TrNz6jU5jMaNGGmkgH-tj5kj-DIpI

i test it with Codetyphon and Lazarus works fine

to sign it
https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin

On 10.12 (Sierra) or later with SIP, you need to run this:
echo "set startup-with-shell off" >> ~/.gdbinit