# Unknown ending signal when using debugger gdb

Tags: c, macos, gdb

I have installed GDB on Mac OS X and to test that it works I have used this following C program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int *my_array = (int *) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        my_array[i] = i;
    }

    free(my_array);

    return 0;

}
```

I have an error when compiling it, which is normal (segmentation fault)

However, when **adding the -g flag** in the compiling command and running gdb on my compiled program, I have this message after launching the command **run**

```
During startup program terminated with signal ?, Unknown signal.
```

Really don't know where it comes from. I have added a certificate to ensure that gdb works correctly on OS X but I have found nothing to fix this issue.

Comment: You should try the solutions below and indicate which one helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're on Sierra , that's expected.
GDB isn't compatible with macOS Sierra , even the last release (7.12).

We should maybe wait for another release of GDB , or for another update for macOS in order to get the bug fixed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702871/gdb-kind-of-doesnt-work-on-macos-sierra.

Comment: Be sure to scroll down, there might be a solution listed below

Comment: Also, just for the records, it doesn't work on High Sierra (Version: 10.13.2 (17C88)) either.  I get the same error: `During startup program terminated with signal ?, Unknown signal.`

Answer (score 32):

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40437725/1060955

> This is how I easily fixed the issue. [Update: based on feedback received and yet to be verified, it seems that this solution works with macOS Sierra 10.12 but not with macOS Sierra 10.12.2]
>
> See video instructions here
>
> Quit gdb
>
> Using your text editor e.g. Sublime Text, save a file called “.gdbinit” [Exclude the quotation marks] in your user folder.
>
> In the file add the following: “set startup-with-shell off” [Exclude the quotation marks]
>
> Save the file
>
> gdb should now work

Sources

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40437725/1060955

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7684629?start=0&tstart=0

Where is .gdbinit is located and how can I edit it?

https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Starting.html

Comment: Worked for me after signing gdb. To simplify, you can run these commands from Terminal: `touch ~/.gdbinit;set startup-with-shell off>~/.gdbinit`

Comment: the commands is wrong. `touch ~/.gdbinit;echo "set startup-with-shell off">~/.gdbinit` is right

Comment: Unlike the above comment, if you do not want to delete your current `~/.gdbinit`:  `touch ~/.gdbinit; echo "set startup-with-shell off" >> ~/.gdbinit`

Answer (score 11):

I installed gdb via Homebrew.
At the end of the installation it says:

> On 10.12 (Sierra) or later with SIP, you need to run this:
>
> ```
> echo "set startup-with-shell off" >> ~/.gdbinit
> ```

This was necessary to make it work. Also I had to make sure the `.gdbinit` was set in the Eclipse Debug configuration

Comment: It works on High Sierra 10.13.2 together with gdb 8.0 (installed from sources) and Visual Studio Code.

Comment: GDB Manual for gdb version 8.2.50.20190106-git; page 28 states for this error: `(the error) which indicates the shell or the wrapper specified with ‘exec-wrapper’ crashed, not your program.`, hence this solution worked.

Answer (score 5):

For me it worked perfectly on **MacOS Sierra Version 10.12.4** by just uninstalling and installing gdb as,

1. Uninstall GDB

> $ brew uninstall gdb

2. Install GDB

> $ brew install gdb

This will install latest gdb which is compatible with MacOS Sierra.

Hope this help to anyone!

Answer (score 2):

Sierra (10.12) doesn't seem to support `gdb`. I tried following a tutorial that had me create a certificate. Afterwards, when I ran `gdb`, I got the same error mentioned.

Apple uses `lldb`. It works well, and can integrate with Eclipse, I've been told. Here is a [link](http://lldb.llvm.org/tutorial.html).

Comment: Downvoted because Sierra will support gdb if you follow the instructions above.
echo "set startup-with-shell off" >> ~/.gdbinit
You also have to create a certificate for gdb to work: See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49001329/gdb-doesnt-work-on-macos-high-sierra-10-13-3
Yes, it's a hassle but it's worth having gdb.
You can optionally run 'brew doctor' to make sure your code is up to date.