# Gdb debug "terminated exit value: 0" error eclipse on mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, gdb

I've been trying to install gdb to debug using eclipse on my mac with no luck, I followed both of those guides with no success:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdcpDOf5Sog
[second guide in other comment - can't add more than two links due to new user limitations]

I'm attaching a screenshot to demonstrate:
[Gdb "terminated exit value: 0" eclipse on mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dqbr.jpg)

Each time I hit the Debug button I get the same "treminated exit value: 0" error (the code runs perfectly when I hit the run button). Gdb **does** respond to terminal command "gdb"

I've been researching for quite long and it seems that no one has experienced the same problem I do. (Macbook pro 2016 10.12 Sierra)

I've heard from a friend that I might need to configure my Mac to "developer" mode, I have xcode up and running, but I have no idea what else should I do. Anyway I'm my friend could not guarantee that it is the cause of the problem.

Comment: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/macmingweclipse/allexperimental/mac-gdb-install.html

Answer (score 1):

I had issue with terminated exit value: 0 while using older gdb 7.11 because my 7.12.1 does not work on Sierra 10.12.4. There was no solution for my case.

Easy WA is to use LLDB as a debugger for now. Sample instructions [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_get_the_LLDB_debugger.3F)

Another LLDB instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39778562/7988540)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Consider adding some essential details as links can become invalid later on but info. here will remain beneficial.