# NetBeans debugger problems on macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-8, macos-sierra

I'm programming in C++ and I'm not an expert. I'm trying to run the debugger using gdb throw Netbeans, but it's still showing this message:
"During startup program terminated with signal SIG113, Real-time event 113."

Any advices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GDB kind of doesn't work on macOS Sierra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702871/gdb-kind-of-doesnt-work-on-macos-sierra)

Comment: It's still unsolved for macOS sierra 10.2.3

Comment: Apple changed security once again... File a bug with `NetBeans` and let their developers steal a fix from some other debugger :)

Comment: So is your advice to contact NetBeans staff? :)