# gdb os x sierra 10.12.3 not working

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, gdb, macos-sierra

the problem is already known, that gdb doesn't work with OS X Sierra anymore.

This is really annoying, since I researched already about the solution, and there were some solutions, but they apparently don't work anymore. I tried to use the .gdbinit file solution and the disable csrutil solution, both doesn't work.

Sooo my question is: Does anyone know how to fix it in 10.12.3 ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try to compile latest [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)  7.12.1 from source code?

Comment: See also http://sourceware-org.1504.n7.nabble.com/gdb-on-macOS-10-12-quot-Sierra-quot-td415708.html

Comment: thank you very much, you gave me the idea to simple update gdb lol. It helps, I figured out myself then ! :) I will write the answer in a post for the dudes in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So thanks to Basile Starynkevitch, who just gave me the idea to update gdb

**SOLUTION:**

You simply have to **update** gdb for the latest version (which is 7.12.1 currently). Assuming you have installed Homebrew:

That's what I did:

```
brew update 
brew remove gdb
brew install gdb
```

It has now updated to the latest version.

Now codesign gdb again with the cert that you used before.

```
sudo killall taskgated
codesign -fs gdb-certi /usr/local/bin/gdb 
launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.taskgated.plist
```

Last step is still to use the workaround to create the .gdbinit file:

```
nano ~/.gdbinit
```

-> `set startup-with-shell off`

Debugging works for me now :) (*OS X Sierra 10.12.3 - gdb 7.12.1*).

**UPDATE:**

Apparently it will fix certain problems, but not the whole problematic itself. It will still cause errors. Honestly, my solution: When you can: Switch to LLDB and another IDE **(Netbeans does not support LLDB)**. Or use Linux. I currently use Ubuntu with a stick on my MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there still isn't a solution to this. I don't think "use LLDB instead of GDB" is the ultimate solution. So I went ahead and built a fairly basic docker container which contains the very basics (g++ and gdb).

Here is the [Docker Hub container](https://hub.docker.com/r/shahzeb/cpp-gdb/), and the the Dockerfile is on this [Github repo](https://github.com/shahzeb1/cpp-gdb-docker-image).

This solution at least allows you to use GDB on your Mac via a couple simple commands. And since the folder you're coding on is mounted, as soon as you hit save, all your changes appear automatically.

Hope this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

None GDB 7.11 or 7.12.1 will not work on Sierra 10.12.4 In short it's  because of Apple security upgrade. We need to wait for re-enabling when some new version will shows up.

Easy WA is to use LLDB as a debugger for now. Sample instructions [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_get_the_LLDB_debugger.3F)

Another LLDB instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39778562/7988540)

Answer (score -1):

I found that gdb 7.12.1 did not work for me either. I do not think it includes the crucial commit   82b19a4d2f9c9e8d56f to gdb made on the 9th Nov 2016.
I was able to get the gdb 8.0 development branch to work, however.

Download with, e.g.

```
git clone --depth 1 --branch gdb-8.0-branch git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
```

Then go into the checked-out directory

```
cd binutils-gdb
```

I have macports so (a) wanted to link to macports libraries and (b) wanted to avoid putting stuff in /usr/local so configured with

```
./configure prefix=$HOME LDFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/local/include"


make -j8

make install
```

=> puts gdb executable into ~/bin; (static) libraries into ~/lib; documentation into ~/share

Then follow André's tip above to do the code signing; though it will now be
codesign -fs gdb-certi ~/bin/gdb