# Mac OS Sierra 10.12.4 GDB debugger

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb, macos-sierra

I am just curious as to whether GDB works at all on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.4. I know that there are fixes for Mac OS Sierra 10.12.3 here:

[gdb os x sierra 10.12.3 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42320878/gdb-os-x-sierra-10-12-3-not-working)

Any ideas on how to get GDB working on 10.12.4 would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has been recommended that you must use lldb with Mac Os. Avoid using gdb with Mac. All the debug activities you can do with lldb.