# gdb on macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Tags: gdb, macos-sierra

There are lots of help around regarding the incompatibility of Sierra and gdb, and everyone says that the best solution is waiting.

The problem seems to still persist, could anyone please help me how I can solve it?

I have already tried this and it does not work on my Sierra.

[GDB kind of doesn't work on macOS Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39702871/gdb-kind-of-doesnt-work-on-macos-sierra)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix has been created, but not merged and released yet.  In the meantime, I have patched the most recent release of GDB with the changes and have things working with the latest version of Sierra.  You can access my repo below and compile from scratch.  Be sure to code sign the new binary and "set startup-with-shell off" in .gdbinit.

https://github.com/joshwells/binutils-gdb

Comment: Just provide some basic steps to make sure you are giving a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

None GDB 7.11 or 7.12.1 will not work on Sierra 10.12.4 In short it's  because of Apple security upgrade. We need to wait for re-enabling when some new version will shows up.

Easy WA is to use LLDB as a debugger for now. Sample instructions [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#How_do_I_get_the_LLDB_debugger.3F)

Another LLDB instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39778562/7988540)

Comment: Thanks, it downloads and installs fine, but unfortunately cannot work well with my IDE (Netbeans 8.2)

Comment: Yes, Netbeans is not supporting LLDB. The only solution is run with Eclipse IDE.